# Wordpress : anonymous function error in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am having **anonymous function** error in my WordPress website. When I open my browser JavaScript console, it shows the error in this line:

```
$(".accordion."+tech).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
```

I am using **WordPress** and above code is inside `( function( $ ) { } )(jQuery );`.

Also I have included this JavaScript file in my footer with the following code:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: What exactly is the error that it is giving you?  Are you loading jQuery before loading your script?

Comment: if the site is online what is the url

Comment: Site is not live yet coz of some issues :/

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** When I expand this there is anonymous function error.

Comment: you are using `.show()` in a wrong way...see here http://jsfiddle.net/ae8kkz4g/

Comment: @Kartikeya Let me try this.

Comment: even if you remove `{direction:right}` the effect you will get will be the same ... updated fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/ae8kkz4g/1/

Comment: if you want to give directions or something else then you have to use animations with .show()..